# How make video chat between red5(server) and android(client)?

Tags: android, red5

After tried lot i didn't get simple video chat using red5(server) and android(client).

i need to do two way video chat. one end is my android app and other end is android browsers / desktop browser.
both end should communicate.

is there any possibility?if it there then where should i start . it will more helpful if any examples.

note: i'm using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to use Adobe AIR for mobile. If you have any experience with Flash, Flex, or AS3 you should be up and running in no time.